# How to display details on the right panel of tablet in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, layout, xamarin

I have this layout in xamarin:

[image: Tablet Screen]

On the left panel are the list of Orders.
Every time you click an item, it should be displayed on the right panel.
But what happens is this, the detail pop ups:

[image: Details]

This is the code for the details:

```
    public class InProgressFragment : Fragment, SwipeRefreshLayout.IOnRefreshListener
    {
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
        SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
        InProgressAdapter mAdapter;
        List<DTO.Order> mOrders;

        void OnItemClick (object sender, int position)
        {
            var InProgressDetailsActivity = new Intent (Activity, typeof(InProgressDetailsActivity));
            InProgressDetailsActivity.PutExtra ("TransactionID", mOrders [position].TransactionId);
            InProgressDetailsActivity.PutExtra ("UpdatedBy", mOrders [position].UpdateBy);
            InProgressDetailsActivity.PutExtra ("DatePaid", mOrders[position].DatePaid != null ? 
                mOrders [position].DatePaid.Value.ToString ("ddd, MMM d h:mm tt", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture ("en-US")) : "n/a");
            InProgressDetailsActivity.PutExtra ("Remarks", mOrders [position].UserRemarks);
            InProgressDetailsActivity.PutExtra ("ShippingMethod", mOrders [position].ShippingMethod);
            InProgressDetailsActivity.PutExtra ("CustomerName", mOrders [position].UserName);
            InProgressDetailsActivity.PutExtra ("AddressPK", mOrders [position].AddressPartitionKey);
            InProgressDetailsActivity.PutExtra ("AddressRK", mOrders [position].AddressRowKey);
            InProgressDetailsActivity.PutExtra ("Paid", mOrders [position].Paid);

            StartActivity (InProgressDetailsActivity);  
        }
.
.
.
```

And here is the View under `layout-large`. The detail view is just a mockup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f2f2f2"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/GrabhutToolbar" />
            <com.refractored.PagerSlidingTabStrip
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:pstsDividerWidth="0dp"
                app:pstsDividerPadding="12dp"
                app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
                app:pstsIndicatorHeight="5dp"
                app:pstsUnderlineColor="#000000"
                app:pstsTabPaddingLeftRight="14dp"
                app:pstsIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                app:pstsDividerColor="#ffffff" />
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                tools:context=".MainActivity" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
<!--' DETAILVIEW '-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:padding="16dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/details">
            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/GrabhutToolbar" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:padding="16dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:minWidth="25px"
                    android:minHeight="25px"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="16dp">
                        <TextView
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/TransactionID"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                            android:textColor="#ffec6206"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:text="TRANSACTION ID" />
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp">
                            <TextView
                                android:text="Processed By : "
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:textColor="#ff505050" />
                            <TextView
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/ProcessedBy"
                                android:textColor="#ff797979" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp">
                            <TextView
                                android:text="Paid On : "
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:textColor="#ff505050" />
                            <TextView
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/DatePaid"
                                android:textColor="#ff797979" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                            <TextView
                                android:text="Remarks : "
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:textColor="#ff505050" />
                            <TextView
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/Remarks"
                                android:textColor="#ff797979" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="16dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
                        <TextView
                            android:text="Shipping Details"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="#ff505050"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp">
                            <ImageView
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_local_shipping_grey600_48dp"
                                android:layout_width="24dp"
                                android:layout_height="24dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
                            <TextView
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/ShippingMethod"
                                android:textColor="#ff797979"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp">
                            <ImageView
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_room_grey600_48dp"
                                android:layout_width="24dp"
                                android:layout_height="24dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
                            <TextView
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/Address"
                                android:textColor="#ff797979"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp">
                            <ImageView
                                android:src="@drawable/user"
                                android:layout_width="24dp"
                                android:layout_height="24dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
                            <TextView
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/CustomerName"
                                android:textColor="#ff797979"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                            android:minWidth="25px"
                            android:minHeight="25px"
                            android:gravity="right">
                            <Button
                                android:text="SCHEDULE"
                                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:background="@color/orange"
                                android:id="@+id/Schedule"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/orderitems" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use fragments? It's the best for your case, [check here about fragments and dual panel](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/fragments_walkthrough/part_1_-_walkthrough/)
Also i dont see the reason to intent so many data, you can use the Application class to store your whole object this way:

```
namespace myApplication
{
[Application]
public class myApplication : Application
{
public bool enabled; {get; set;}
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        enabled = false;
    }
}
```

And to use this object in this way:

```
App _app = (App)Application.Context;
_app.enabled = true;
```